# Get results that does not contain in array in cosmos db

Tags: arrays, azure, azure-cosmosdb, contains

In cosmosdb there is the support of ARRAY CONTAINS. But what if we want to get a result that does NOT CONTAIN some properties? Is there something that supports this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [Array built-in functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-array-functions) supported by cosmos db,there is no opeartor to implement your need.

So,you could use `JOIN` and `Not In` opeator:

```
select c.array from c
join c.array in b
where b.column not in ('111','222')
```